# Combine scale_x_upset with scale_y_break

Tags: r, ggplot2, axis, upsetplot

I made an upset plot using the `ggupset` package and added a break to the y axis with `scale_y_break` from the `ggbreak`package.

However, when I add `scale_y_break`, the combination matrix under the bar plot disappears.

Is there a way to combine the combination matrix of the plot made without `scale_y_break` with the bar plot portion of a plot made with `scale_y_break`? I can't seem to be able to access the grobs of these plots or use any other workaround. If anyone could help, I would greatly appreciate it!

Example with `scale_x_upset` and `scale_y_break`:

```
df = tidy_movies %>% distinct(title, year, length, .keep_all=TRUE)

ggplot(df, aes(x=Genres)) + geom_bar() + scale_x_upset(n_intersections = 20)+ scale_y_break(breaks = c(750,1000))
```

I would like to combine the barplot portion of the plot created with:

```
df = tidy_movies %>% distinct(title, year, length, .keep_all=TRUE)
ggplot(df, aes(x=Genres)) +  geom_bar() + scale_x_upset(n_intersections = 20)+ scale_y_break(breaks = c(750,1000))
```

with the combination matrix portion of the plot made with:

```
df = tidy_movies %>% distinct(title, year, length, .keep_all=TRUE)
ggplot(df, aes(x=Genres)) +  geom_bar() + scale_x_upset(n_intersections = 20)
```

Thanks!